# Calculate total working hours where hours passed as a number

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I am using FLEX version 3.0
I want to calculate the total working hours. I am giving you the details and what i have done in it.

```
var a:Number = 2.00;
            var b:Number = 2.00;
            var c:Number = 1.45;
            var d:Number = 1.30;

            var total:Number = a+b+c+d;
            var totalmin:int = total;
            var temp:Number = total - totalmin;
            var tem2:Number = 0.60 - temp; 
            var workhour:Number = 0;

            while(total >= 0)
            {
                workhour += 1;
                total -= 1.00;  
            }

            var tot:Number = workhour + tem2;

            txtTotal.text = tot.toString();
```

I want result 7.15 not 6.75.
currently i am getting 6.85... please Help to solve this issue.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You say you're giving us the details, but you haven't explained anything about the input. What are a, b, c and d meant to represent? How do you *expect* the code to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked a lot on this one and find one of the interesting questions.....
and i have found the correct answer for that.. Keep posting that interesting questions.

here is the code.

```
var a:Number = 2.23;
var b:Number = 2.36;
var c:Number = 1.18;
var d:Number = 1.13;

var totalHours = 0.0;

var inta:int = a;
var numa:Number = a - inta;
var intb:int = b;
var numb:Number = b - intb;
var intc:int = c;
var numc:Number = c - intc;
var intd:int = d;
var numd:Number = d - intd;


var total:int = inta + intb + intc + intd;
var totalsec:Number = numa + numb + numc + numd;
var tempsec:int = totalsec * 100; 

var temp:int = tempsec/60;

total += temp;

var sec:Number = tempsec - (temp*60);

sec = sec/100;

totalHours = total + sec;

txtTotal.text = totalHours.toString();
```

Comment: Congrats, you just reimplemented the basics of Date class ! ^^

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is you're working with ten based values, but hours are 60 based values. So 1,5 hour doesn't mean 150 minutes, as in a decimal system (1.5 meters means 150 centimeters, for instance), but 90 minutes.

My advice : use the native Date class, or choose to work only in a unit to be consistent in your maths. But the Date class is made for these purposes. Substracting two Date.getTime() and then converting the result to a new Date gives you what you want.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but i am giving that hours statically in number. that's why i am facing this problem. otherwise its very simple for me... thanks again.

Comment: You mean that when you give, say, 0.5 hour, it means half an hour ?

Comment: no it 0.5 means 0 hours and 50 minutes.
having a validation that no one can enter value between 0.61 to 0.99 even not 0.00
If user enters 2.23 it means 2 hours and 23 minutes

Answer (score 0):

For what you want

```
        var a:Number = 2.00;
        var b:Number = 2.00;
        var c:Number = 1.45;
        var d:Number = 1.30;

        var total:Number = a+b+c+d;
        var totalmin:int = total;
        var temp:Number = total - totalmin;
        var tem2:Number = temp - 0.6; // !!!This line changes!!!
        var workhour:Number = 0;

        while(total >= 0)
        {
            workhour += 1;
            total -= 1.00;  
        }

        var tot:Number = workhour + tem2;

        txtTotal.text = tot.toString();
```

Comment: This only works if the minutes are greater than 60. If the minutes are less than 60 then leave the minutes as is. You should really be using a modulo function though.